# Can Firefox Containers be used to mitigate CSRF attacks?

Tags: firefox, security, login

> [Firefox Multi-Account Containers](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/multi-account-containers/) lets you keep parts of your online life separated into color-coded tabs that preserve your privacy. Cookies are separated by container, allowing you to use the web with multiple identities or accounts simultaneously.

Can this Firefox extension mitigate [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attacks?

For example, consumer network devices often have poor security, including vulnerabilities to CSRF.  Suppose I only login to local network devices using a container, and I don't use that container for anything else.  I am hoping this would stop websites using a CSRF attack against my network devices.

---

(I used to use Private Browsing to achieve this. It doesn't work for me now, in `firefox-91.0.2-1.fc34`.  Private Browsing doesn't remember self-signed HTTPS certificates, even if you use a non-private tab to add them to the list of exceptions).

Comment: Not broadly (CSRF is a rather broad category of attacks), but will thwart attempts to steal cookies owned other containers. Additional features of Total Cookie Protection should help prevent cookie theft as well.

Comment: @FrankThomas an accepted answer beckons if you have an example that disproves my own... that's exactly what I was trying to provoke here. Including the realistic chance that my idea of what CSRF is is a misconception :-).

Comment: Or, are you saying this needs a better phrasing to distinguish "is the mechanism secure enough to prevent CSRF attacks between different containers" from "will installing this extension and not doing anything else automatically prevent all CSRF attacks"? If so, do you have any ideas for such phrasing?

Answer (score 0):

The addon page makes no promises about security.  However, the idea seems reasonable based on the design.  It is also supported by the [historical Wiki page on Containers](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Security/Contextual_Identity_Project/Containers#Benefits_and_Use_Cases).

> 5. Isolates a site's credentials to a container, helping prevent CSRF, clickjacking, or other attacks which rely on the presence of ambient credentials.
>
> A user has their online banking sites open in the banking container. An attacker attempts to exploit a CSRF by tricking the user into clicking a link on Facebook (open in the Home container). The CSRF is sent without the bank's credentials and the attack fails.